# After creating a b2c user using the graph api, still get to a signup view

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, azure-ad-b2c

Flow:

- on angular front-end (FE) there is a call to create a user, first I create a user in my identity server 4 (IS4) runing on .net core.
- from there is4 makes a request to b2c graph api to create a b2c user, and gets a success response
- after the success response i send the email to the user with the link to continue the onboarding process
- user cliks link, autoredirects to b2c, which auto redirects to is4, user puts in credentials, goes back to b2c and ends up on create b2c user page instead of redirecting back to FE
- if i only click continue on b2c signup page it says "You are already registered, please press the back button and sign in instead."
- if i click the link in the email again, everything works fine

This bug happens only once in a while, and I assume that the b2c user, although created is still not ready for use. If I disable signup part of a custom user flow, the app keeps redirecting for a few seconds getting the error in address bar

- error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90037:+An+error+occurred+while+processing+the+request.+Please+contact+administrator+of+the+site+you+are+trying+to+access)
- AADB2C90037 error is for missing objectId

After a few redirects it finally finds the b2c user, and after that everything works fine.
Does anybody know how I can make sure b2c user is ready for use, before calling the signin process?

Comment: Hi @Milan Kablar. How are you linking the Azure AD B2C user with the IdentityServer identity?

Comment: I am sending subjectId (base64 encoded) from my identity server in the graph api request to Azure AD B2C when creating a B2C user - was following Microsoft documentation when creating a post request to graph api

Comment: Does the subject identifier that you are writing to Azure AD B2C from IS4 during registration match that that is issued by IS4 for Azure AD B2C during login?

Comment: Yes. Everything works if I wait half a minute before making the first call to B2C. It is just that if I make a call to B2C within the first 5-30 seconds after creating a user, that it is showing that error.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/D6bYwrCZ
Here is the code for the 2 methods working with graph api

Comment: I believe you're experiencing the side effects of the eventual consistency of the directory architecture (see the "Data consistency" section in the [What is the Azure Active Directory architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-architecture) article. i.e. It can take a few moments to replicate a **user** object from a write replica (to which the user object is written by IS4) to a read replica (from which the user object is read by Azure AD B2C).

Comment: That makes sense. What do you propose, just to put a timeout, or try to get the user from the graph api on identity server, and then when I am sure that the user is reachable, only then to send the email?

Comment: Hi @Milan. Yes, I suggest you delay sending the e-mail to the user for 5--30 seconds, so that as soon as the link is opened by the user then they shouldn't experience the sign-in issue.